# Is it an optimal way in Swift for the function to return more than 2 types?

Tags: swift, optimization, enums, tuples

I need to have function that should return secure random **String** or **Data** with future possible extension with other types.

I start looking for the suggestions and find out that this could be done via **Enums** and **Tuples**.

I decide to proceed with **Enums**.

My implementation:

```
enum SecureRandomInput {
    case forString
    case forData
}


enum SecureRandomOutput {
    case forString(String)
    case forData(Data)

    static func generate(with type: SecureRandomInput, bytesCount: Int) -> SecureRandomOutput {
        var randomBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bytesCount)
        let _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, bytesCount, &randomBytes)
        switch type {
        case .forString:
            return SecureRandomOutput.forString(randomBytes.map({ String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }).joined(separator: ""))
        case .forData:
            return SecureRandomOutput.forData(Data(bytes: randomBytes, count: bytesCount))
        }
    }
}
```

So questions are:

1) Usage of the Enums in particular situation is more flexible than Tuples?

2) Do you have any suggestions about that part of code? (What could be done better)

3) Are any other ways how we could achieve required behavior in Swift 4? (without Enums and Tuples)

Comment: If that is your code from an actual project (not stub, pseudo or example code) *and* is working as expected *and* you are looking for reviews and possible improvements, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask. See also https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users for SO vs CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I agree with you, that enum is more clear way to separate different behavior instead of creating massive tuple.
2. Code is pretty standard.
3. IMO, this situation also can be handled by regular class or struct if there are any kind of large amount of shared data for both results (init/generate some things, like `SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, bytesCount, &randomBytes)` or so). For now it's good, but in future it can be one option to refactoring the code.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go is with closures and generics

```
func generate<T>(bytesCount: Int, convert: ([UInt8]) ->T ) -> T {
    var randomBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bytesCount)
    let _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, bytesCount, &randomBytes)
    return convert(randomBytes)
}

let x = generate(bytesCount: 7) {
    return Data(bytes: $0, count: $0.count)
}

let y = generate(bytesCount: 7) { bytes in
    return bytes.map({ String.init(format: "%02hhx", $0) }).joined(separator: "")
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer it is grate way with generics.